# Declare variable based on object value in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, object

Simple issue I ran up against today and can't seem to find a way around it, whatever the solution is it's something I've never learned so leaving me stumped.

For reasons I won't get into, I need to get a value from an object and use it as the name of a new variable. Will be looping through a ton of these so needs to be repeatable. For example from an object like so,

```
obj = {
    "name": "object101"
};
```

What I want to get out of that is a var declaration in such a way that object101 is the name of the new var,

```
"var object101 =  // stuff"
```

---

But  `"var obj.name =  // stuff"` is not working, the dot is not valid it seems.

I also tried putting the object101 into it's own var like, `var name = obj.name;`.

Which holds the content fine. But then I immediately saw the hilarious problem with going, `var name = // stuff`

It just redefines "name" and is not placing the content of name. It does render right when in a console log like `console.log("var "+name+" = stuff");` which is pretty much exactly how I want it to write to the code, but having this issue in the real code with the var being redefined in this case.

So I feel like I am missing something very basic in how you can provide the name to declare a var. Maybe some very simple syntax thing I am missing, or perhaps there is a process out there which will dynamically make a var declaration name based on some other object. I've done my fair share of js and never seen `var [complex syntax resulting in name] =`, it's always quite simple.

But my searching has drawn a blank so far on this exact issue. Anyone able to enlighten me?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. There's a reason you've never seen that syntax, because it doesn't exist... Why do you want to do this? Maybe we can help find a solution to your actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, you *really* don't want to do what you think you want to do, but here goes.

If you are operating in a browser and you want the variables to be in global scope, fortunately the global scope has a name: `window`.

You can just do this:

```
window[obj.name] = 'stuff';
```

If you want it in in local scope, you can use the almost-forbidden keyword `with`:

```
var f = function(obj, b) {
  var fake_scope = {};
  with (fake_scope) {
    fake_scope[obj.name] = b;
    console.log(d);
  }
}

f( { name : 'd' } , 3 )
```

will print out 3.

If you need local scope and you don't want to use `with`, you will have to screw around with `eval`.

But seriously, if you do this, [remember](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvKgd.jpg).

Comment: Thank you Malvolio! The "Scope[ObjectReference] =" syntax was what I had never seen and needed to understand here. [Does what I need](http://jsfiddle.net/2yfFp/), hopefully your answer will be useful to anyone else in the same boat as I was.

Comment: @user2844700 -- OK, well, enjoy, but we are all worried that you and anyone else in the same boat as you were are headed for an iceberg, so be careful.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the interest of science:

```
(function() {
  var dynaVarName = 'testName';
  eval('var ' + dynaVarName + ';');
  eval(dynaVarName + ' = 5;');
  eval('console.log(' + dynaVarName + ');');  // => 5
}());

testName // => ReferenceError
```

So yes, you actually can create a local variable with a name based on an expression. I can't imagine the benefits of doing this though.

Comment: Well, I upvoted you, but [this image](http://i.imgur.com/V0qwXiw.jpg) expresses my opinion on the matter.

Comment: There is no need for the second two *eval* statements, only the first is required.

Comment: @RobG You mean I can concatenate the strings from the 3 evals? Yes I can. But this way I prove that the newly introduced variable persists once `eval` is done.

Comment: You could also build a function body and use the Function constructor, but I guess that's more or less the same as *eval*. The OP hasn't explained what they are trying to do, so very difficult to suggest a solution. Object properties are the usual solution (though anything using *with* is nasty).